# How to get number of identity ID from newly added record in SQL Server table? (asp.net)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, auto-increment

Here's what I'm trying to do: I add a record to the table. This record receives its unique ID number (identity). Then I want to use this ID in my code. How can I find out which ID number has just received a newly added record in my SQL Server database table?

Comment: Please kindly search in SO, before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Add an output parameter to your insert statement and return scope_identity(). If this isn't sufficient just search my answer, it will be in here a bunch.